# how to check for non used variables in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I am wondering if there is an option in xcode that will let you debug a variable to see if it's being used in your code anywhere?

I find sometimes I make changes to my code, then I look at all of my synthesised variables and I'm just not positive that they are being used.. I don't mind going through my code and checking but I thought it would be more productive if their was a function that would help me do this quicker?

Dose anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `Unused parameter warnings` in the Build Settings of your project. Just search "Unused" when looking for the option.

Comment: got it! I was looking at unused variables.. lol :) worked perfectly.. app showed about 60 something unused paramteres lol :(

Answer (score 3):

Product -> Analyze will also show variables that are not read, which sometimes can capture more unused variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch the compiler to `LLVM/GCC` or just `LLVM`, then run "[Analyze](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html)" (<kbd>CMD+SHIFT+I</kbd> I think, might be <kbd>CMD+SHIFT+J</kbd>) it will put a warning next to any unused variables/ivars/properties.